# What do these terms related to airfoils mean?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

I keep coming across some terms related to airfoils and I'm not able to find clear definitions for these terms.

- Bubble ramps
- pressure recovery
- suction side

Comment: @mins I understand how a bubble is formed, but what is it that is referred to as a ramp?

Comment: A ramp is a mild positive pressure gradient which destabilizes the boundary layer so the bubble will develop. Without a ramp, bubble location on the suction side will vary  a lot over angle of attack. When transition has happened, the steep pressure recovery may follow (but not sooner).

Comment: Thanks, are transition ramp and bubble ramps the same thing?

Comment: Whether a bubble forms depends on the Reynolds number, but essentially yes.